# C++ rename function not working with absolute path

Tags: c++, rename, absolute-path

Part of my program needs to get a file path from the user and then move and rename said file.

If I use the relative path like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int check;
    char oldname[] = "images//test_1.jpg";
    char newname[] = "images//test//test_2.jpg";
    check = rename(oldname, newname);
    if (check == 0)
        puts("Success");
    else
        perror("Failed");
    return 0;
}
```

It works perfectly.

But if I try to use the absolute path like this:

```
char oldname[] = "c://path//images//test_1.jpg";
char nername[] = "c://path//images//test//test_2.jpg";
```

it fails and says "Failed: No such file or directory"

I am sure its some silly mistake but no matter how many times I double check my file path and code I can't figure it out. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Oh and if it makes any difference I'm working in linux.

Comment: linux doesn't have a C:\, and you don't need to use double slashes only double backslashes

Comment: I'm actually compiling through a linux server that I am logged into with PuTTY and the drive is 'H:\' the file paths in my code example are just for examples not the actual path. Also, I actually used '//' by mistake in my code but changing it to '\\' has made no difference.

Comment: Make sure `image/test` exists.

Comment: Wait - you're compiling on a linux machine and then running it where? It doesn't matter if the the H: drive exists on your windows machine if you're running on the server. Try dropping the c: from the test path and see if it works

Comment: It is compiling and running in linux. But my workstation is actually Windows, I am logged into the linux server (which can access my files in my H:/ drive) remotely. Also, I double checked images/test and it does exist. I tried dropping the c: (actually H: but you get the idea) and nothing changed.

Comment: Okay, the exact path to my file is now H:/images/test_1.jpg my source file however is in a different directory with a more complicated messy file path. I am still unable to rename the test_1.jpg image unless I put it in the directory of my source file.

Comment: It's likely that the only way the linux os is accessing the H: drive is through an emulation of a mount point somewhere else.  Try a local file

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. But I have written various programs that create and write to files all the time using this setup. And this code works so long as I put the images into the directory with my source file (which is also on the H:/ drive).

Comment: Avery, I believe you were correct. I simply do not fully understand the file structure in Linux. I have only recently begun using it and the whole setup is somewhat confusing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is running on the linux server, you need to use the path on the linux server. You can use `pwd` to print the working directory (which will give you the absolute path that you are currently in). Also you can use a relative path with `..` to go up a directory. For example your directory structure may be like this

```
code/
    main.cpp
    main.h
    a.out

images/
    yourimage.png
```

So you could do:

```
$ pwd
/home/user/code
```

and then your absolute path to the image would be

```
/home/user/images/yourimage.png
```

Or you could use a relative path from the code directory

```
../images/yourimage.png
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I needed. Evidently I do not fully understand how this server works. On my machine the drive is listed as H:/ but while in the "drive" on Linux I typed pwd and got a path /home/user/etc... Anyway, I fixed path in my program and got it to work. Thanks for your help!